# Should the question start with "how to"?

Tags: discussion, title

I started editing various titles to be more meaningful. In general on stackoverflow (but not only there) most of the questions are howto questions.

I am wondering what should be correct title here:

- How to do x?

OR

- Doing x

Is there any content standard which could be used as a referrence?

Comment: There are some title tips in the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page.

Comment: Probably not, most of them turn out being poorly researched, not giving complete code samples, or having other issues.

Comment: The question title just needs to 1. explain what the question is about at a basic level and 2. allow other people with the same problem to find it. Phrasing it as a question likely isn't going to help with either of those, so there's nothing really gained from edits that do so, especially if they're not addressing other issues with the post.

Comment: On Meta.SE: [Should question titles begin with "how to"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178454)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't waste your time editing titles to add or remove a trivial phrase like "How to". Titles can come in a variety of phrasing styles. What's important is whether they coherently and concisely summarize the question being asked.

If you do feel the title needs to be rewritten to be improved, try to fix any other obvious issues you see with the question at the same time (broken code formatting, poor grammar, etc.). Don't shotgun a series of edits, take a little time to make sure you're doing your best to improve each question.

Answer (score -6):

According to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page it is correct to have how to in the title. Moreover it improves searching (you may search for how to as well unless you have the deviation like code not working or error message)