# 'How do I' vs 'How do you' vs 'How to'

Tags: discussion, title

When asking a question, should I be writing from a [first, second, or third person perspective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19769/what-do-first-second-and-third-person-perspective-mean-why-are-they-so-called)?

I've noticed that many of the top posts vary between these three styles. While it isn't an issue for existing questions, I'm a bit unsure whether new questions should generally try to adhere to one style over the other.

**First person** (How do I)

- [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery)
- [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)
- [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

**Second Person** (How do you)

- [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)
- [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)
- [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

**Third Person** (How to)

- [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)
- [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)
- [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css)

Comment: "How to [...]?" is not even grammatically correct.

Comment: @BoltClock That's what I thought as well. However, looking at the [top voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), there seemed to be an equal amount of "How to" questions versus "How do I"?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro How does that affect BoldClock's comment?

Comment: @Steven Vascellaro: A large portion of the userbase are non-native English speakers, so, unfortunately, it's not realistic to expect most questions to have a well-formed title. The worst offender is "5W/1H <subject> <verb>" - I practically *never* see 5W/1H questions written correctly anymore.

Comment: @BoltClock  I wasn't entirely sure which style was preferred, as I generally see a large amount of "How to" question titles. Hence why I posted this question.

Comment: Different question, but [same answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303608/366904). It doesn't matter whether you write in first, second, or third person. It matters that the title is clear and provides an adequate summary of the question. It is not productive to micro-manage stuff like this.

Comment: In that case, I strongly object to making the site worse by butchering the language to cater to the non-native speaking majority.

Comment: @CodyGray I was more-so asking for my own sake. While making others adhere to a style isn't critically important, it seems that in general "How do I" or "How do you" are preferred

Comment: "How does one ...".  This really, really doesn't matter.  Google doesn't care.

Comment: Well, yeah. In general, *prefer* a grammatically correct formulation. Prefer *not* to obsess about it.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro All anyone has told you is that the title should be grammatically correct, and that some of your examples aren't.  Nobody has told you that there's anything wrong with a question using the 3rd person perspective, or that you should prefer one perspective over the other.

Comment: Since down votes on Meta mean "I disagree", do the down votes on this question mean that voters do not think this distinction as important? Or that none of these options is correct, because for example, [starting questions with How decreases the speed with which they can be read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)? Or something else?

Comment: That's the fun part, @Cecilia! You can never know! But if I were to hazard a guess, it'd be the downvotes are because people don't think this is important enough to bother with. That's my read of the comments. (Except, I made that comment, and I upvoted this question. So NOBODY KNOWS!)

Comment: This is one of those style things that doesn't make a question more clear or grammatically correct that people change while editing anyway because they're certain their way is right. These are fine.

Comment: I think it would be a useful Eagle Scout project to go through these tens of thousands of posts and edit them to make them consistent.

Comment: @torazaburo: m e t a

Comment: You have omitted another key aspect of this question, which is whether it's preferable to say "How do I", "How can I", "How could I", "How would I", or "How should I".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think this is a real issue. Other than my pet peeve of "How to [...]?" questions being grammatically incorrect, I don't see any meaningful difference between "How do *I*" and "How do *you*", other than the fact that the word "you" alone makes the quality filter freak out about the question possibly asking for opinions or anecdotes.

The grammatically correct third-person form is "How *does one*", but again, sitting on the three options is just wasting your time. Just pick one and go with it. And don't worry too much about the quality filter (unless you're the sort who's prone to asking subjective questions). What's important is constructing a *meaningful* title with the right keywords.

Editors about to edit questions with such a title, even if it's in the grammatically incorrect "How to" form, should refrain from doing so if their intention is to edit *only* the title. Such a title edit would be too minor anyway.

Comment: I don't agree with you about grammar. It seems to me that Stack Overflow question titles, like newspaper headlines and other kinds of titles, follow a slightly different grammar to English *prose*, and that the question fragment *"How to foo the baz in C++?"* is a perfectly grammatically correct *Q&A title* (even though it's not a complete English question) in the same way that the sentence fragment *"Man accused of hamster molestation*" is a perfectly grammatically correct news headline (even though it's not a complete English sentence).

Comment: There was a study done somewhat recently that found questions whose titles used proper grammar and were phrased as a question (e.g. "How do I do X?" or "Why is my Z not doing Y properly?") resulted in more and better answers, over all. I can't find it right now, but it's probably listed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data

Comment: @Mark Amery: It's true that headlines do follow a different set of rules, but it is *still* incorrect to punctuate a "How to" headline with a question mark. Also it's a little strange to see a question with a non-interrogative "How to" title that doesn't actually contain the how-to content from the get-go, but that's just me.